# Where to set PYTHONPATH for pre-down command in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

How do I make `sudo -E` really preserve it's environment. Assume I have a

```
pre-down python /usr/local/myscripts/pre_down.py
```

in my `/etc/network/interfaces with`/usr/local/myscripts/pre_down.py`

```
import a
```

and `/home/user/scripts/a.py`

```
print 'a'
```

and `/home/user/scripts/__init__.py` present, why does `sudo PYTHONPATH=/home/user/scripts ifdown eth1` cause

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/myscripts/pre_down.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
ImportError: No module named a
```

? I know that writing a sh script as wrapper solves the problem (tried and succeeded with content `PYTHONPATH=/home/user/scripts /usr/local/myscripts/pre_down.py`), as well as manipulating `sys.path` before the import statement. I'm asking in order to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

The [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/interfaces.5.html) of `interfaces` states:

```
   All of these commands have access to the following environment variables.

   IFACE  physical name of the interface being processed

   LOGICAL
          logical name of the interface being processed

   ADDRFAM
          address family of the interface

   METHOD method of the interface (e.g., static)

   MODE   start if run from ifup, stop if run from ifdown

   PHASE  as per MODE, but with finer granularity, distinguishing the pre-up, post-up, pre-down and post-down phases.

   VERBOSITY
          indicates whether --verbose was used; set to 1 if so, 0 if not.

   PATH   the command search path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

   Additionally, all options given in an interface definition stanza are exported 
   to the  environment  in  upper  case  with "IF_" prepended and with hyphens
   converted to underscores and non-alphanumeric characters discarded.
```

So it seems these scripts do not inherit the environment of the commands `ifup` or `ifdown`